# Can I bind a form from a model automatically somehow?

Tags: scala, playframework

So I have the following methods on my User controller:

```
def create

def onCreate

def edit(userId: Int)
```

Create displays a new form, onCreate handles the post back.

Edit loads the model by the id and then it is suppose to display the form with the values pre-populated.

Can I bind my model to my form or do I have to manually set the properties?

```
val userForm = Form(
  mapping (
    "name" -> text,
    "age" -> age,
    "location" -> text
  )(UserForm.apply)(UserForm.unapply)
)

case class UserForm(name: String, age: Int, location: String)

case class User(name: String, age: Int, location: String)
```

I was hoping I could easily bind my form to the model without having to manually do it.

Is it possible?

*If not, how do I pre-populate the form using my model?*

Comment: Is there supposed to be a difference between `User` and `UserForm`?

Comment: @LimbSoup Not at this time, but eventually yes my form will get more complicated. My form won't have the same properties as my model.

Comment: I don't think so, I believe that's why they call it **typesafe**..